# is it possible to simulate file upload form?

Tags: php

I'm trying to test a file upload function.  This function I'm trying to test is where the file data is posted to from a form.

Is there a way to test this function without the need of an upload form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct an HTTP programatically with the [cURL library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). Google throws up [this example](http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/uploading-a-file-using-curl-in-php.html).

Comment: the "example" is no longer available